# Django cache display image issue

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, memcached

I'm picking random ImageField from database and saving its result in cache for 10 seconds and display it in one of my templates. For some reason after 10 second I don't see a different image, which is my goal. I'm using memcache.

Part of my get_context_data(self, **kwargs) from Class Based View:

```
    ...
    dummy_images = DummyImage.objects.all()
    dummy_images_counter = DummyImage.objects.all().count()

    random_image = get_object_or_404(DummyImage, pk=dummy_images[random.randrange(0, dummy_images_counter)].id)
    cache.set('image', random_image, 10)
    context = {'width': width, 'height': height, 'img': cache.get('image')}
```

Template:

```
 {% load static %}
 <img src="{% static "dummy_images/images/" %}{{ img.image.url }}" width="{{ width }}" height="{{ height }}">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `cache` in every execution. Do a check before that.

```
cached_image = cache.get('image')
if not cached_image:
    random_image = get_object_or_404(DummyImage, pk=dummy_images[random.randrange(0, dummy_images_counter)].id)
    cache.set('image', random_image, 10)
    cached_image = random_image
context = {'width': width, 'height': height, 'img': cached_image}
```

Comment: Still whenever I refresh it shows the same picture.